# Average of element in list of dictionaries with CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have to make a function that takes two arguments(name of the .csv files), in which it calculates the average of the age of a certain person's pets.

I have two CSV files. The first one contains the info of the pets. Like this: [image]

The second one contains the name of the owner's and which pets they own.Like this:[image]

My functions needs to read this .csv files and return another .csv file with the average of the pets age, differenciated by their owner's. For example, John has three pets (Michalengelo, Leonardo and Raphael), so the functions reads the two .csv files and calculates de average of John's pets age. The same goes for Adam and Eva.

I have a function that takes the csv file and turn it into a dict. For example (with the first csv file):

```
read_csv_to_dict('Pets_info.csv'):
>>> [{'Age': '8', 'Name of the Pet': 'Felix', 'Species': 'Cat'}, {'Age': '57', 'Name of the Pet': 'Michelangelo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': '12', 'Name of the Pet': 'Rantanplan', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': '2', 'Name of the Pet': 'Nemo', 'Species': 'Fish'}, {'Age': '45', 'Name of the Pet': 'Leonardo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': '9', 'Name of the Pet': 'Milo', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': '57', 'Name of the Pet': 'Raphael', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': '4', 'Name of the Pet': 'Dory', 'Species': 'Fish'}]
```

I think if I manipulate these data with the dictionaries I can get what I want, I just don't know how to do it.
Feel free to ask any questions if you don't undertand mine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) module which you can learn in 10 minutes.

> **Consider your data is like this in separate csv files:**

[image]  [image]

> **And this is what you can do in pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd
#Read input csv files
own = pd.read_csv('OwenerPet.csv')
pet = pd.read_csv('PetAge.csv')
#Merge the dataframes on 'Pet Names'
ownpet = pd.merge(own,pet, on=['Pet Names'], how='inner')
#Group by owners and get the avarage
ownpetaverage = ownpet.groupby('Owners Name').mean()
#Print it, you could also save it by saying ownpetaverage.to_csv('average.csv')
print ownpetaverage

                   Age
Owners Name
Adam          7.000000
Eva          28.000000
John         22.666667
```

Comment: I am new to python and I'm not quite understanding the use of the panda module....

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am using Idle and it says that there is no module name pandas, how can I install it on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

```
pets.txt

Name of the Pet,Species,Age
Felix,Cat,8
Michelangelo,Tortoise,57
Rantarplan,Dog,12
Nemo,Fish,2
Leonardo,Tortoise,45
Milo,Dog,9
Raphael,Tortoise,57
Dory,Fish,4

owner.txt

Owner's Name,Pet Names
John,Michelangelo
Eva,Dory
Adam,Rantarplan
John,Leonardo
Eva,Felix
John,Raphael
Eva,Nemo
```

Python code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l_pets = pd.read_csv('pets.txt')
l_owner = pd.read_csv('owner.txt')

l_merged = l_pets.merge(l_owner,how='inner',left_on='Name of the Pet',right_on='Pet Names')
l_groupded = l_merged.groupby(by="Owner's Name")

print l_groupded.aggregate(np.average)
```

Output

```
                    Age
Owner's Name
Adam          12.000000
Eva            4.666667
John          53.000000
```

Comment: It gives me a Key Error : 'Pet Names'

Comment: This happens when the input file and code has wrong column names. The owner.txt should be:   \n Owner's Name,Pet Names
John,Michelangelo
Eva,Dory
Adam,Rantarplan
John,Leonardo
Eva,Felix
John,Raphael
Eva,Nemo  \n and the pets.txt should be: \n Name of the Pet,Species,Age
Felix,Cat,8
Michelangelo,Tortoise,57
Rantarplan,Dog,12
Nemo,Fish,2
Leonardo,Tortoise,45
Milo,Dog,9
Raphael,Tortoise,57
Dory,Fish,4  \n I have used the column names as per your screenshot only.

Comment: All the column names are in that order and correct, I don't know why it's giving me an error

Comment: Please can you paste your code as well as input files

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide both the input files, the code and its output.

Comment: Oh I see now, the problem is that the files are .csv files not .txt